Magento order notification
I want to retrieve order details whenever an order is placed or updated in Magento. Currently, I am working on integrating orders with CRM. Therefore, whenever an order is created or updated in Magento, I need to receive the specific details of that order. Destination should be my function's REST API URL. What are the possible ways to do this?

In a custom module create an observer for the event sales_order_place_after
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="custom_module_observer_sales_orderplaceafter_sales_order_place_after" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderPlaceAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>

You can then pass the data to your API.
class OrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {


        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
        $total=$order->getGrandTotal();
        
        // pass order data to api or message queue

    }
}

A better solution is to pass this process to a message queue so that your api call is performed asynchronously as demonstrated in this module https://github.com/gaiterjones/Magento2_MessageManager

You can use default Magento events to observe specific events which are suitable for your CRM Requirements.
For example,
checkout_submit_all_after --> triggers after you place an order from frontend
paypal_express_place_order_success --> related to Paypal express
sales_order_invoice_register --> After the invoice gets registered
sales_order_shipment_save_after --> after shipment is generated
order_cancel_after --> After the order is canceled
You can utilize these default events and use more events or plugins for any custom order-related functionalities.
Please mark this answer accepted, if it helped.
Thanks!
